# how to pivot a table to reflect row values as columns?

Tags: sql-server, row, pivot

SQL returns the following table from the query:

```
Application  FDate        Type   Value
-----------  ------      ----   ------
abcd         04/15/2013  CIndex  3.00
abcd         04/15/2013  CC     200000
abcd         04/15/2013  MI     400
xyz          04/15/2013  CIndex  2.50    
xyz          04/15/2013  CC     15000    
xyz          04/15/2013  MI     1200
```

I am trying to get the following result with the pivot:

```
 Application  FDate        CIndex   CC     MI
-----------  ------       ----   ----   -----
 abcd         04/15/2013  3.00   200000  400
 xyz          04/15/2013  2.50   15000   1200
```

Query so far:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT A.App_Name AS [Application],
  O.Functional_Date As FDate,
  CASE WHEN (T.TYPE_NAME LIKE 'Calculate Index') THEN 'CIndex'
  CASE WHEN (T.TYPE_NAME LIKE 'C Complexity') THEN 'CC'
  CASE WHEN (T.TYPE_NAME LIKE 'Medium Index') THEN 'MI' END TYPE,

CASE WHEN (T.TYPE_NAME LIKE 'Calculate Index') THEN ROUND (V.TypeValue, 2)
ELSE V.TypeValue END Value

FROM [DBServer1].[DB_A].[dbo].TypeTab AS T, [DBServer1].[DB_A].[dbo].AppName AS A,    [DBServer1].[DB_A].[dbo].DateTab AS O, [DBServer1].[DB_A].[dbo].ValueTab AS V 

WHERE T.Type_ID = V.Type_ID
      AND T.Type_index IN (0,1)... (several ANDs)
) src
PIVOT
( SUM (Type)
)piv
```

But this throws error. And not sure even if i fix the error the query is going to work.

Please help.

Thanks in anticipation!
Ashish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  [Application], 
        FDate,
        [Calculate Index] AS CIndex,
        [Cyc Complexity] AS CC,
        [Medium Index] AS MI
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  A.App_Name AS [Application],
                    O.Functional_Date As FDate,
                    T.TYPE_NAME,
                    ROUND (V.TypeValue, 2) Value
            FROM    [DBServer1].[DB_A].[dbo].TypeTab AS T, 
                    [DBServer1].[DB_A].[dbo].AppName AS A,    
                    [DBServer1].[DB_A].[dbo].DateTab AS O, 
                    [DBServer1].[DB_A].[dbo].ValueTab AS V 
            WHERE   T.Type_ID = V.Type_ID AND 
                    T.Type_index IN (0,1)... (several ANDs)
        ) org
        PIVOT
        (
            MAX(Value)
            FOR TYPE_NAME IN ([Index], [CC], [MI])
        ) pvt
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. But i have to use alias for the Type_Name using case statements. I get Invalid column name 'Type_Name' in the Pivot